# Can I choose which of my dual screens a youtube video will maximize to?

Tags: chrome, multi-monitor, youtube

Watching a youtube video, I click on "maximize to full screen" (the flash button). It maximizes to the wrong screen. How can I choose which screen will display the video?

Comment: Does it maximize to a screen different than the screen the browser is on?  What OS and is it 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: @penguin - yeah, it maximizes to a different screen. Ubuntu 10.04, 64 bit.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: @Kave - if I have, I don't remember it any more, sorry.

Comment: I found the solution. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/window%20expander%20for%20youtube?_ac=0  This extension solves it. :)

Comment: @Kave - cool! You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on your window manager, but in KDE Flash maximizes to the display the browser is in.  It may not work as expected if your browser window spans across two displays.  What I do is move the browser window to say the left screen, then hit maximize, it will be maximized on that left screen.

I don't know of any way to leave the browser on the right display and have it maximize on the left.

Comment: My browser window does not span, and still maximizes to the other display.